# How can I track the time it takes a block of my MVC3 code to execute?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

My MVC3 application is not running as fast as I hoped. I'd like to find out if some of the database look ups are taking too long. Is there a way that I can time part of a block of code within a controller. For example:

```
var a = the_time_now;
...
...
var b = the_time_now;

<log the code area name and time b - time a
```

I am fairly new to MVC and would appreciate any advice. Note that I currently have no uses on my system so if I was logging the time then it would not load things down too much :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Stopwatch class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) for the code execution time tracking. this is not titly bound to MVC, this is used generally in .net Framework